# Custom token not being replaced by actual value when I have send email

Tags: exm

I have created custom token using steps provided by Sitecore.
when I have send an email it will not replace token value

https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/exm/90/email-experience-manager/en/create-a-custom-personalization-token.html

https://doc.sitecore.com/users/90/sitecore-experience-platform/en/configure-the-import-contacts-wizard-to-include-custom-contact-facets.html

Token NAME : $typeofcustomer$

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Seems like "*typeofcustomer*" is your custom facet, make sure you've configured everything correctly for custom facets. I've explained in below blogs.
https://sitecorewithraman.wordpress.com/2020/08/02/sitecore-xconnect-custom-facets-part-i/
https://sitecorewithraman.wordpress.com/2020/08/22/sitecore-xconnect-custom-facets-part-ii/

Once you're sure, your custom facet is set up correctly and values are being saved against that facet. Follow below steps for custom token:

**1. Create a custom dispatch task:**

- Create a custom dispatch task class Eg. CustomerDispatchTask.cs -> In this class, in the GetContacts method, return your custom facet along with default facets.[image]
- Update the *Sitecore.EmailExperience.ContentManagement.config*
  [image]

**2. Override the default token map:**

- Create your custom token map by adding your custom token. Eg. CustomerPropertyTokenMap.cs
- Replace the recipients/recipientPropertyTokenMap element in *App_Config\Sitecore\EmailExperience\Sitecore.EmailExperience.Core.config* file with your custom token map.
  [image]

Refer to this post: https://sitecorewithraman.wordpress.com/2021/01/10/sitecore-exm-custom-tokens/